# Change in Print Settings only works on first iteration of For loop

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

The code below is the code I have to set not only the print area, but margins and that the sheet is to fit onto one page.  This code is wrapped up into a for loop that has many other sections both before and after that work just fine (so its not the 'Next i' being in the wrong place). This code will only work on the first iteration and will not work for any other iteration (each iteration includes code to create a new sheet that works just fine).

Why is this only working once? How do I get it to work on all iterations?

```
Application.PrintCommunication = True
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(53, 29)).Address
Application.PrintCommunication = False

With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .LeftHeader = ""
    .CenterHeader = ""
    .RightHeader = ""
    .LeftFooter = ""
    .CenterFooter = ""
    .RightFooter = ""
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .PrintHeadings = False
    .PrintGridlines = True
    .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
    .PrintQuality = 600
    .CenterHorizontally = False
    .CenterVertically = False
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .Draft = False
    .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
    .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
    .Order = xlDownThenOver
    .BlackAndWhite = False
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 1
    .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
End With
```

Comment: You're doing all this with the ActiveSheet property.  When your next iteration creates a new sheet, is it being Activated?  If not, this code is working but it's just re-applying it to the first sheet.

Comment: @techturtle Yes, this code is place immediately after creating the sheet and pasting the template into the sheet. I have verified that it is in fact the current active sheet each time it gets to this point in the code.

Comment: Even so, I think techturtle is right that your code is setting the print area in the same place every time.  Try explicitly defining the range of your print area as on the active sheet like `Activesheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(53, 29)).Address`.

Comment: @KarlRookey Tried. Didn't make a difference.

Comment: Can you post the full loop with the code that activates the sheet you have just created?  It really seems like if there was a problem with this code you would get an error, and using essentially the same code as yours, I'm able to set print areas on multiple sheets by setting focus on that sheet before I do it (or defining the range on that specific sheet). Are you sure there's no way the focus can be getting moved from the sheet before this code runs?